# game invitation by PHP SDK to other friends without request dialog?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, intel-xdk

is it possible to send game invitation to the friends using PHP SDK , i dont want to use java script dialogues because i am unable to run them on intel XDK.. Though intel XDK for htmlt5 has already a plugin but that only works with ios and android. So i thought writing up a php script would be better idea to send Invitation to user and this way i can easily open this page on the mobile app...but i am stuck because i could not find a way without JS ... I am new in facebook apis kindly advise ..

Comment: Pretty sure there SDK already have a PHP library for what you want?

Comment: I'm not that active on facebook lately, but it's perhaps good if you're stuck with that because these invitations are always spammy as hell.

Comment: I think the request dialog is only available in the JS, iOS and Android SDKs

Comment: there is no library i could found yet for inviting user using php without request dialog...i searched everything but everywhere people are talking about JS ...

Comment: I'm guessing what you need is to use the "InAppBrowser" feature. You'll find it in the Cordova API documentation.